# Wrapper not storing values in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, force.com

I am storing values in wrapper from UI input:
***Component is like (on press of submit button, calling Controller)***

```
<aura:component controller="AccountCreationFormClass" implements="force:appHostable>
<aura:attribute name="AccountWrapper" type="CommonWrapperClass.AccountCreationWrapperClass"/>
<ui:inputText value="{!v.AccountWrapper.Name}" />
<ui:button label="Submit" press="{!c.Submit}"/>
```

***Wrapper class is like***

```
public class CommonWrapperClass{
    public class AccountCreationWrapperClass{
@AuraEnabled public String Name {get;set;}
public AccountCreationWrapperClass(){
            Name = '';
  } 
 }
}
```

***Component is like (showing only submit part)***

```
Submit : function(component, event, helper){
        var objAccount = component.get("v.AccountWrapper");
        console.log("Individual Values: " + objAccount.Name);  // Values are shown    
        console.log("Value of ObjAccount1: " + JSON.stringify(component.get("v.AccountWrapper"))); // Values not shown
        console.log("Value of ObjAccount2: " + JSON.stringify(objAccount)); // Values not shown
        console.log("Value of ObjAccount3: " + objAccount);   // Values not shown
    }
```

When I am trying to see values from individual component of the wrapper (where ever: // Values are shown comment), its showing user entered values but values are not showing up from wrapper (where ever: // Values not shown comment)

***Here is my doInit where I am assigning default values***

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){        
        var tempArray = [];
        tempArray.push
        ({
            "SYField":"",
            "AccountNumber":"",
            "Name":"ABC",
            "Type":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Sic":"",
            "Active":false,
            "NumberOfEmployees":0,
            "AccountPriority":"",
            "SalesYear":""
        });
        component.set("v.AccountWrapper",tempArray);     

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69441/discussion-on-question-by-saurabh-singh-wrapper-not-storing-values-in-controller).

Answer (score 0):

Attribute "AccountWrapper" is not of type list. And you are assigning Array to this variable. Try using this.

```
var a = new Object(); 
a.name = 'Test'; 
// All the fields ; 
component.set("v.AccountWrapper",a);
```